# Development of simple C# application for understanding Resharper Open APIs

Tags: c#, resharper

I wanted to start developing plugins for Resharper using its Open API.

As there is very less documentation available, for starters I wanted to develop a simple C# application to extract the class details (eg. class name, number of methods in a class etc), so that I can understand the working of Resharper library and the in-built functions it provides.

It would be ideal if I can extract these details and print it on the console, for ease of testing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to parse the code yourself, that's a bit more complicated. The following is a *rough* outline of how you could go about parsing a file.

```
var buffer = new StringBuffer(sourceCode);
var lexer = LexerFactory.CreateLexer(buffer);
var defines = EmptyArray<PreProcessingDirective>.Instance; // assume there are none
var parser = new CSharpParser(lexer, defines);
var file = parser.ParseFile() as CSharpFile;
```

Now you can use `file` to navigate the code structure.

BTW, I strongly recommend using F#. It's made for this sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. 
I pretty much understood the logic of your code, but are they resharper built-in functions? I couldnt find them. I would like to use any built-in functions to get the details of the parsed C# file.

Comment: @Shaun Of course they are. `StringBuffer` is in `JetBrains.Util`, the parsing stuff is in `JetBrains.ReSharper.Psi.CSharp`, and you will of course need `JetBrains.ReSharper.Psi` in there too. To start with, I recommend you add a reference to all ReSharper DLLs to your project - that way, you'll be able to auto-import missing symbols from whichever assembly is appropriate.

Comment: @Shaun Whoops.. just realized that some of those classes are internal or private. Here's a correction: use the `CSharpLanguageService` class instead. It has methods for creating both the parser and the lexer.

Comment: Are you talking about the abstract class in JetBrains.ReSharper.Psi.CSharp.CSharpLanguageService?? But I do not intend to create functions for parser or lexer. I just want to use an inbuilt functions to do these functions. I am not sure if I am looking into the right thing. Pls provide some pointers. Thanks

Comment: @Shaun please contact me via dn/at/jetbrains/com or on skype (dmitri.nesteruk)

Answer (score 3):

in terms of documentation, there is some info available on the [Developer Wiki](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+6+Plugin+Development), with more to come. You might also want to check out the [ReSharper Extensibility Guide](http://nesteruk.org/blog/page/ReSharper-Extensibility-Guide.aspx), which is a bit oudated but still relevant.

As for your question of how to examine the file structure - guess what - you don't even need the API! Here's what you need to do:

- Start Visual Studio using the `/ReSharper.Internal` key. This will enhance the *ReSharper* top-level menu with an *Internal* section.
- Pick `ReSharper-->Internal-->PSI Viewer`. This will pop up a form similar to the following: [image: illustration]
- Now, click the Create button, which will let you create a file, statement, expression or member declaration.
- The bottom pane will then illustrate the parsed structure and let you navigate it.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you Dmitri. The details seen in the PSI Viewer or even the PSi browser (internal -> windows -> PSI browser) is really good.
But I was really interested in handling all these details from my code itself. 
I think we can access the parse tree by using JetBrains.ReSharper.Psi, but I am not sure how we can input a .cs file and then extract its file structure. So it will be really helpful if you can put up a small snippet for fetching the number of classes in a file or some example like that. It will really help me give a head start.

Comment: @Shaun Ahh, in that case, let me write another proper reply.